# TS2322 error while trying to use specific key and value in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to achieve this for a reducer used in ReactJS, but can't find the way.

```
type Filters = {
  hidden: boolean | null,
  status: number | null,
  // ... other filters omitted
}

type FilterPayload = {
  [key in keyof Filters]: Filters[keyof Filters]
}

type Action = { type: 'set-filter', payload: FilterPayload }
  //... other unions omitted

function dispatch(action: Action) : void
```

The problem here is that `FilterPayload` value can be any of `Filters` values, so TS is complaining when I try to put it in a `Filters` object :

```
let filters: Filters = {
  hidden: null,
  status: null
}

filters = { 
  ...filters, 
  ...action.payload // <- error
}
```

It results in the following error:

```
error TS2322: Type '{ hidden: number | boolean | null; status: number | boolean | null; }' is not assignable to type 'Filters'
  Types of property 'hidden' are incompatible.
    Type 'number | boolean | null' is not assignable to type 'boolean | null'.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'boolean | null'.
```

Is there any way to solve this without writing every possible combination ?

Comment: TS is somehow inferring number as possible type for hidden key checkout why its getting number as possible type of hidden

Comment: While I'm not strong with TypeScript, I really can't imagine what is hoped from `FilterPayload`, that strange `[]:[]` construct appears to make all fields typed as the aggregate of every single type appearing in the fields of `Filters`, that's what the error message complains about afterwards. What's wrong with `type Action = { type: 'set-filter', payload: Filters }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [`Partial`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) utility type is what you're looking for. Its implementation already adds an [optional mapping modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers).

```
type FilterPayload = Partial<Filters>;
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgG2BATgZygXigbwFBRQAWcAJqRAHYBcUARgPYMIQCGlUAPlJQK4IIANAShpgrYLzS0%20AWzqouPfkLwBfQnjyhIsRMhQAFViAQNWpLFGMpgcVggA88JKjQA%20ANxad0AIIAxnYMHNg4UL60AORoEMAAtABm%20qhRglBgJmYWtC4Gxqbmlmp4FAEIrCjQASFiUKxBcCG0gcGU3qUQ5ZXQibyUjSFQpHBomcABRAAUDW0tg5QAlFC0AG4MZB0swFDJrui5KehW%20IQk5FQyKsKEYhJSVwLqWnsGGGFQIgB0P69u6d8frMmpQvplChYoAB6KFQRzxHgMKCoFAMFDqIA)

Answer (score 0):

Got it, was pretty close, but I had to use the `key` in the `FilterPayload` value and add [an optional mapping modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers) to make other keys optional :

```
type FilterPayload = {
  [key in keyof Filters]+?: Filters[key]
}
```